# How many significant figures in this negative number?

Tags: arithmetic

I understand that $0.03$ would have $1$ significant figure.

Does $-0.03$ also have one significant figure or $3$?

Thanks.

Comment: The tag shouldn't be (complex-numbers). Maybe something simpler...

Comment: @coffeemath: Yes, there's an edit pending so I couldn't commit a tag edit to "number-systems", although "approximation" might be apt.

Answer (score 1):

For negative numbers, to find the number of significant figures, you can find the number of significant figures of the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

$0.03$ and $-0.03$ have the same number of significant digits (or *figures*), namely one.